# Getting different time while saving record on server. How to save client date and Time on Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.Net MVC I am inserting Date and Time on the server but while inserting Date Time it takes server Time may be. 
How to save client machine time? It should not be like this I think. But I am facing this issue.

My code is:

```
string enteredDate = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
query += "INSERT INTO tblLoginHistory(LoginId, LoginDateTime) VALUES(";
query += " '" + UserName + "', '" + DateTime.ParseExact(enteredDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "')";
```

But I am getting error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Are your machines out of sync? Fix that! If not, what exactly is the difference? Different time zones?

Comment: you should use DateTime.ParseExact() may be?

Comment: use DateTime.ParseExact(string date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: i tryed to use DateTime.ParseExact() but its not working

Comment: try DateTime.ParseExact(enteredDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: I used DateTime.Parse(enteredDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) and it workes..... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the time from the client machine, you can use JavaScript to get the date (and time) when the form is submitted.  Then you include this in the data that is posted to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Open SQL Server Management Studio  and add record tblLoginHistory manualy then see datetime format

Looks this article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

### Example Code

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or

Convert your datetime value in query using `Convert(DateTime, format )`

Convert [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)